# jQuery .ajax XHR request via setInterval doesn't work properly on Raspberry PI Chromium

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chromium, raspberry-pi3

I'm struggling making the right piece of code with jQuery.

In a nutshell, I want to check if something is completed via XHR request every 1000ms. It **does work perfectly on any desktop machine** but does n**ot work properly on latest raspberry pi** with **chromium** installed.

The client have only one shot on getting HTTP/1.0 200 OK, the thing is the raspberry pi could miss it time to time and it's really annoying.

```js
var my_interval = null;

var k = function()
{

  $.ajax({
            url: '/my-ext-request',
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success:  function(data) 
            {
            console.log('Success!!');
            clearInterval(my_interval);
            },
            error: function(jHXR, exception, m)
            {
            console.error('Error!');
            }
        });

}

$(function() {
   my_interval = setInterval(k, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Could anyone propose a better way to do this ?
Thank you!

Comment: First off, don't use setInterval with ajax calls.  Use a setTimeout that repeats within one of the callbacks.  You have no guarentee that the request will finish within your timeframe and can lead to requests stacking

Comment: Agreed. But I set async: false globally, It's should act like setTimeout. This I don't understand.

Comment: Don't do that.  async: false not only causes the request to be non asynchronous, which is counter to the paradigm, but also freezes the browser for the duration of the request, which is terrible user experience.  Use setTimeout instead.  EDIT: Additionally async: false was removed in jquery 3.X

Comment: Will do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not use setInterval, but setTimeout instead.

@Taplar :

> Don't do that. async: false not only causes the request to be non
>   asynchronous, which is counter to the paradigm, but also freezes the
>   browser for the duration of the request, which is terrible user
>   experience. Use setTimeout instead. EDIT: Additionally async: false
>   was removed in jquery 3.X